# Prevent height and width of images from being set to 1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress WooCommerce plugin here to display the products and it has an issue where some product images are not getting displayed because the `width` and `height` values are automatically set to 1.

```
<span class="">
  <img height="1" width="1" alt="0001702_black-metal-bar-stool_600" 
       class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" 
       src="http://aalampana.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/0001702_black-metal-bar-stool_600.gif">
  <span class="cart-loading">
    <i class="fusionicon-spinner"></i>
  </span>
</span>
```

Can any one please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you checked  WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display ?

Comment: yes i am checked that is fine.

Comment: I have reworded the sentences to improve grammar, added a relevant tag, improved code block formatting. While it is not a big issue, always try to avoid scrollbars as much as possible in code blocks because that makes all the code visible to others at first glance itself. I have also reworded your title and removed out the plugin names. They are not required because of the presence of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use Either CSS or JS

CSS:

```
.attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image{
    width:100%; height:auto;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width");
```